# Multiple Spark DataFrame mutations in a single pipe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider a Spark DataFrame `df` with the following schema:

```
root 
|-- date: timestamp (nullable = true) 
|-- customerID: string (nullable = true) 
|-- orderID: string (nullable = true) 
|-- productID: string (nullable = true)
```

One column should be cast to a different type, other columns should just have their white-space trimmed.

```
df.select(
  $"date",
  df("customerID").cast(IntegerType),
  $"orderID",
  $"productId")
  .withColumn("orderID", trim(col("orderID")))
  .withColumn("productID", trim(col("productID")))
```

The operations seem to require different syntax; casting is done via `select`, while `trim` is done via `withColumn`.
I'm used to `R` and `dplyr` where all the above would be handled in a single `mutate` function, so mixing `select` and `withColumn` feels a bit cumbersome.

Is there a cleaner way to do this in a single pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either one. The difference is that `withColumn` will add (or replace if the same name is used) a new column to the dataframe while `select` will only keep the columns you specified. Depending on the situation, choose one to use.

The `cast` can be done using `withColumn` as follows:

```
df.withColumn("customerID", $"customerID".cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("orderID", trim($"orderID"))
  .withColumn("productID", trim($"productID"))
```

Note that you do not need to use `withColumn` on the `date` column above.

---

The `trim` functions can be done in a `select` as follows, here the column names are kept the same:

```
df.select(
  $"date",
  $"customerID".cast(IntegerType),
  trim($"orderID").as("orderID"),
  trim($"productId").as("productId"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.select(
  $"date",
  $"customerID".cast(IntegerType),
  trim($"orderID").as("orderID"),
  trim($"productID").as("productID"))
```